# Passing json to aws glue create-job after replacement done using jq

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, jq, aws-glue

I have the following bash script that I execute in order to create new Glue Job via CLI:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
NAME=$1
PROFILE=$2
SCRIPT_LOCATION='s3://bucket/scripts/'$1'.py'

echo [*]--- Creating new job on AWS
aws glue create-job --profile $PROFILE --name $NAME --cli-input-json | jq '.Command.ScriptLocation = '\"$SCRIPT_LOCATION\"'' ./resources/config.json
```

I'm using **jq** as i need one of the values to be replaced on runtime before i pass the **.json** as *--cli-input-json* argument. How can i pass json with replaced value to this command? As of now, it prints out the json content (although with value already replaced).
Running the command above causes the following error:

```
[*]--- Creating new job on AWS
{
  "Description": "Template for Glue Job",
  "LogUri": "",
  "Role": "arn:aws:iam::11111111111:role/role",
  "ExecutionProperty": {
    "MaxConcurrentRuns": 1
  },
  "Command": {
    "Name": "glueetl",
    "ScriptLocation": "s3://bucket/scripts/script.py",
    "PythonVersion": "3"
  },
  "DefaultArguments": {
    "--TempDir": "s3://temp/admin/",
    "--job-bookmark-option": "job-bookmark-disable",
    "--enable-metrics": "",
    "--enable-glue-datacatalog": "",
    "--enable-continuous-cloudwatch-log": "",
    "--enable-spark-ui": "true",
    "--spark-event-logs-path": "s3://assets/sparkHistoryLogs/"
  },
  "NonOverridableArguments": {
    "KeyName": ""
  },
  "MaxRetries": 0,
  "AllocatedCapacity": 0,
  "Timeout": 2880,
  "MaxCapacity": 0,
  "Tags": {
    "KeyName": ""
  },
  "NotificationProperty": {
    "NotifyDelayAfter": 60
  },
  "GlueVersion": "3.0",
  "NumberOfWorkers": 2,
  "WorkerType": "G.1X"
}

usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

aws.exe: error: argument --cli-input-json: expected one argument
```

Comment: If you want to pass the json to the command: `aws glue create-job --profile $PROFILE --name $NAME --cli-input-json "$(jq '.Command.ScriptLocation = '\"$SCRIPT_LOCATION\"'' ./resources/config.json)"`

Answer (score 0):

The command line
`aws glue create-job --profile $PROFILE --name $NAME --cli-input-json | jq '.Command.ScriptLocation = '\"$SCRIPT_LOCATION\"'' ./resources/config.json`
executes the command
`aws glue create-job --profile $PROFILE --name $NAME --cli-input-json`,
takes its standard output and uses it as input to
`jq '.Command.ScriptLocation = '\"$SCRIPT_LOCATION\"'' ./resources/config.json`
(which will ignore the input and read from the file given as argument). Please also note that blanks or spaces in `$SCRIPT_LOCATION` will break your script, because it is not quoted (your quotes are off).

To use the output of one command in the argument list of another command, you must use [Command Substitution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03): `outer_command --some-arg "$(inner_command)"`.

So your command should become:

```
aws glue create-job --profile $PROFILE --name $NAME --cli-input-json "$(jq '.Command.ScriptLocation = "'"$SCRIPT_LOCATION"'"' ./resources/config.json)"
# or simplified with only double quotes:
aws glue create-job --profile $PROFILE --name $NAME --cli-input-json "$(jq ".Command.ScriptLocation = \"$SCRIPT_LOCATION\"" ./resources/config.json)"
```

See https://superuser.com/questions/1306071/aws-cli-using-cli-input-json-in-a-pipeline for additional examples.

Although, I have to admit I am not 100% certain that the JSON content can be passed directly on the command line. From looking at the docs and some official examples, it looks like this parameter expects a file name, not a JSON document's content. So it could be possible that your command in fact needs to be:

```
# if "-" filename is specially handled:
jq ".Command.ScriptLocation = \"$SCRIPT_LOCATION\"" ./resources/config.json | aws glue create-job --profile $PROFILE --name $NAME --cli-input-json -
# "-" filename not recognized:
jq ".Command.ScriptLocation = \"$SCRIPT_LOCATION\"" ./resources/config.json > ./resources/config.replaced.json && aws glue create-job --profile $PROFILE --name $NAME --cli-input-json file://./resources/config.replaced.json
```

Let us know which one worked.